# Grails 1.3.7 + how to stop the execution of Creatcriteria

Tags: grails

I am using Grail 1.3.7

I am executing the createCriteria for domain object which is having large set of data. and taking long time to fetch the results.

How to stop the execution. or is there any other way of implementation.

Thanks 
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any functionality in Grails that allows you to cancel a long running query. For starters, calling `list()` on a Criteria will not return until all the requested results are fetched from the database. I think you need to focus on things that will make the query perform better in the first place:

- Obviously, add more criteria, if possible to restrict the rows
- Use `maxResults` to limit the number of rows returned
- If you don't need all the values in the domain object, use `property` projection to prevent having to create domain objects and reduce memory
- If you need to iterate over a large set of data, use `scroll()` and periodically `flush()` and `clear()` the session to prevent slowdown.