# Hibernate + how to terminate the Hibernate session?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am using Hibernate in grails 1.3.7

for some reason there is huge data in Database. Grails domain object criteria take lot of time of time to execute. Please guide on how to terminate this query? or better way to handle this scnerio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails 1.3.7 + how to stop the execution of Creatcriteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557001/grails-1-3-7-how-to-stop-the-execution-of-creatcriteria)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first understand why the query is taking so long, if you are querying thousands of records then obviously this is going to take some time.

You can control the number of records returned in a query by using the `max` parameter to many queries. Example:

```
Book.list(max:10)
Book.findByTitle("Bar", [max:10])
Book.withCriteria(max:10) { eq 'title', 'bar' }
```

Obviously without seeing your query I can't suggest an example appropriate to your question.